# Django STATIC_FILE doesn't work as i thought?

Tags: python, css, django, static

I've searched for answer for this question, but i havent found any solution for my problem. I want to link css to my project, but just cant handle how STATIC_URL work

```
  <head>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
  </head>
```

it's to much code to post here so here are the links:
settings.py: http://pastebin.com/9Bsg3u1h

And I render with `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` parameter of course.
I got files structure like this:

```
Django_project
 ...
 appname
 templates
 static
```

I tried also to place static directory in many project, in appname, and even in templates.
Can someone explain me how should it look for my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin `static`, not `static` from `staticfiles`:

```
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
  </head>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static

> Django ships with a `static` template tag. You can use this regardless if you’re using `RequestContext` or not.
>
> **Note**
>
> The `staticfiles` contrib app also ships with a `static` template tag which uses staticfiles' `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to build the URL of the given path. *Use that instead if you have an advanced use case such as using a cloud service to serve static files...*